# Custom fetch comparator

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I've just seeded 25k objects into Core Data and therefore will need to perform a comparison of some of the objects before they're fetched; though the Haversine formula. I saw a similar question that advised that all objects must be fetched and then compared, however that will be resource and memory expensive.

Please can you tell me how I can perform this custom comparison through, I assume, a predicate in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the predicate to find objects inside a simple lat-long box (min and max values) and then apply any finer grained distance calculation, filter and sorting on the fetch results.

Comment: what's the maths needed to calculate the min and max values. I imagine that I'd need a multiplier for the origin's lat/lon, but is there a specific method for doing so, I see sin/cos come up quite a lot. edit--- I've just seen this, helps a lot: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80809/calculating-bounding-box-coordinates-based-on-center-and-radius. Thanks for your help.